# Concatenating two arrays in mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to concatenate two arrays:

```
arr1: [{"a":"value"}] 
arr2: [{"b":"value"}]
expected result:[{{"a":"value"},{"b":"value"}}]
vars.arr1 ++ vars.arr2  gives an error when arr1 is null. 

    org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "You called the function '+' with these arguments: 
      1: Null (null)
      2: Object
```

How should I handle the following scenarios:

1. when both the arrays are null
2. when one of the array is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you don't mind getting the empty array when both input arrays are null:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw

var arr1 = null
var arr2 = null

---
(arr1 default []) ++ (arr2 default [])
```